# Custom button to perform excel export in JS Web resource in dynamics crm 365

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-365-v9, powerapps-modeldriven

I'm working on dynamics 365 (9.1.x version) online. I have a requirement to download the excel template using a button in a custom web resource (javascript). I tried this [example1 link](https://community.dynamics.com/365/sales/f/dynamics-365-for-sales-forum/349739/unable-to-download-excel-template-using-custom-button-to-import-data) and [example2 link](http://%20http://teameasi.com/blog/generating-crm-365-word-templates-from-javascript) but I'm getting an excel corrupt file error upon opening the file. Can someone please help me with the exact code for this...i have a deadline approaching and am stuck here.

Comment: What is the template of: an entity's schema?

Comment: "help me with the exact code" how about you post what you have and we can move from there?